# Account number on form W9

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am working on a project as an Individual and I need to fill a [W9 form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf) for tax purposes.

In the field "List account number(s) here (optional)" do I have to put the bank account in which the money I receive go?

Answer (score 6):

According to this link http://taxes.lovetoknow.com/federal-income-tax/w9-tax-form:

The very last line on the personal information section refers to "account numbers." Here, the taxpayer lists any accounts they have with the IRS to pay back taxes or pre-payments for anticipated tax liability obligations. This information is optional and is inapplicable in many situations.

Answer (score 4):

No.just give your social security number and contact info, that's all that's needed.

Comment: In general, that "account number" is not for bank account right? So even for a solo LLC that optional account field not applicable?